# If/Then statement for calculating value based on the value of another item for ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online

In the project I am working on some of my data needs to be doubled. I have created three main attributes. The first is `pedvol`, then there is `intersection`, and finally `fixed_pedvol`.

I want to take all cases of items where `intersection = y` and take the `pedvol` and double it and put that number into `fixed_pedvol`.

And ideas on how to do this on ArcGIS Online? I have been looking into IF/THEN statements and IF/ELSE but I cannot seem to figure this out.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the help documentation about calculating field values on ArcGIS Online: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/calculate-fields.htm

Your Arcade expression should look like this

```
iif($feature.intersection =="y", $feature.pedvol * 2, $feature.pedvol)
```